# In Keras, when should I use input_shape instead of input_dim?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have found the use of input_shape instead of input_dim in Keras, especially in LSTM problems? My concern is that input_shape limits the number of rows in the input. It doesn't leave the scope to give complete Dataframe as input. When should we use input_shape instead of input_dim?

Here are the examples https://machinelearningmastery.com/timedistributed-layer-for-long-short-term-memory-networks-in-python/

Comment: What do you mean by "limits the number of rows"?

Comment: If the shape is 5,1 then you can train it with an array (or dataframe) of dimension 5,1 only. But if you give input_dim=1 then your Dataframe should have only one column but it can any number of rows. Check out the example link too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build on the comment and address the point of confusion. You *can* specify an unknown dimension using `None` to give varying values at runtime. For example, `input_shape=(None, 10)` means varying number of rows each with 10 entries. `input_dim` is just a short cut for specifying the final dimension and is there for convenience.